# Band indexing system of Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

In GEE, when I want to use the select method of the Image object with integer, what is the indexing system, starting from 1 or 0 ?

```
ee.Image('image_ID').select(1) 

// or 

ee.Image('image_ID').select(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 0 based.

```
var image = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2020_v1_8')
print('All bandnames:', image.bandNames())
print('select(0): ', image.select(0).bandNames())
print('select(1): ', image.select(1).bandNames())
```